# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::min()

Tags: laravel-9

I get this problem when I go to update the password. But I do not get this problem when I go to register. Please help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions, so we need to see your code to help you debug your problem.  As explained in [ask],  *if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  For help with this, see [mcve].  For tips on writing questions that are most likely to get answers, see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error, adding the following line in the controller solved the issue:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
```

You need to add this class in your controller to make the rule work.

Official documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-passwords

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).