Forgot Password implementation - Error sendResetLink undefined
We are referring Laravel 11 doc.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/passwords#password-reset-link-handling-the-form-submission
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
  $request->only('email')
); 

At this line its throw error as

ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password::sendResetLink() {"exception":"[object] (
Error
(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password::sendResetLink() at C:\wamp64\www\irpnew\app\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController.php:86)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Found a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72762470/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-auth-passwords-passwordbrokermin
